# Using sourdough starter to brew beer

Tags: yeast-starters

I have no yeast in the house, but I do have a sourdough starter (for bread). I was wondering if it is possible to use sourdough starter in place of yeast?

Googling just found me lots of bread recipes, and this question is the opposite of [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/510).

Comment: You really want to get involved with these people. They will walk you through the process http://www.milkthefunk.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to find the reference, I think it's in a book titled "A Sip Through Time" which is recipes from around the 1500s and on. I thought there was a recipe where they specifically used bread yeast.

I think what I would do would be make a small amount of wort, 1.040 OG, like making a normal beer yeast starter. Cool to happy yeast temperatures, mix a small amount of your sourdough starter and see if it starts fermenting. Do this for a few steps up in wort volume, and see what happens before pitching in your brew.

Comment: "Spread yeast on both Sides of a Tost", is what I remembered I guess, which according to the author is, To spread your semi-liquid yeast onto a piece of toasted bread, and float it on top of the wort.

So not quite what you want, but interesting nonetheless.